# In react, How do I guarantee the value that stored through useState hooks is latest data while user click submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When using the react useState hook. the set function do not update hook value data immediately .In that case ,how could we guarantee this operation : "the user do some operation such as fullfill a form, when user click submit button, the data will be submitted, but the data that stored in state might be the previous data? simple code below.

```js
export default function DragAndDropVideoDisplay(props) {
  const [videoDataList, setVideoDataList] = useState(props.videoData);
  const [displayedVideoDataList, setDisplayedVideoDataList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    props.childRef.current = saveDisplayedVideo;
  },[]);


  // called through the childRef, the user click save function 
  async function saveDisplayedVideo(){
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(displayedVideoDataList));
    console.log(jsonData);
    console.log(displayedVideoDataList);
    console.log(videoDataList);
  }

  //user drag data from left column to right column
  function onDragEnd(result){
      const {destination, source, draggableId} =result;
      if (!destination) {
        return;
      }
  
      if (
        destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
        destination.index === source.index
      ) {
        return;
      }

      const start = source.droppableId;
      const end = destination.droppableId;
      console.log("start :"  + start);
      console.log("end :" + end);
      if(start === end){
        let dragContent = displayedVideoDataList[source.index];
        const newDisplayedVideoDataList = Array.from(displayedVideoDataList);
        newDisplayedVideoDataList.splice(source.index,1);
        newDisplayedVideoDataList.splice(destination.index,0,dragContent);
        setDisplayedVideoDataList(newDisplayedVideoDataList);
      }else{
        let dragContent = videoDataList[source.index];
        const newVideoDataList = Array.from(videoDataList);
        newVideoDataList.splice(source.index,1);
  
        const newDisplayedVideoDataList = Array.from(displayedVideoDataList);
        console.log("draggableId : " + draggableId);
        newDisplayedVideoDataList.splice(destination.index,0,dragContent);
  
        setVideoDataList(newVideoDataList);
        setDisplayedVideoDataList(newDisplayedVideoDataList);
      }
  }
  /*VideoPageLeftTiktokOriginalVideoList is original data,use drag left data to right column(which is displayedVideoDataList). 
  after drag operation end, the user then click save button, click operation whill do in saveDisplayedVideo. i do not write more code like (pass 
    displayedVideoDataList to backend and store it.), just print "displayedVideoDataList" data. 
  */
  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Box
        width="100%"
        height="90%"
        mt="0.5rem"
        bgColor="white"
        display="flex"
        justifyContent="space-around"
      >
        <VideoPageLeftTiktokOriginalVideoList videoData={videoDataList} />

        <VideoPageRightTiktokChooseList videoData={displayedVideoDataList} />
      </Box>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}
```

Comment: As  you call setfunction with values React immediately re-render the component, so there are no chances of submitting previous data.

Comment: You could use value driven input fields if you want to be sure that what's in state is what the user is seeing.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal yeah, from the chrome react component extension ,i see the value changed, but why the console.log print previous data ?

Comment: @JunHuiLi can you please share your code or repo link , so I can answer you very clearly?

Comment: @JunHuiLi that is because the component doesn't have the updated value, if you need to get the updated value, you need to do console.log in a useEffect block and set the value as a dependency in the array. That way you output on the console whenever there's a change, and it outputs the most recent value and not the prev one

Comment: @Sandsten the problem is the user's seeing content has changed, but console log in submitting function print previous value. that's puzzle me a lot.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal thanks ,already provide code .

Comment: @AbdulHannan the console.log result code in useEffect while be correct. but how could guarantee the value is latest when button click event calling (like submit operation). the submit operation code might not in useEffect.

Comment: @JunHuiLi you are using empty array as useEffect dependency that means  even if your states gets updated, useEffect will not render code inside of it.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal the empty array of useEffect dependency is used to bind function through ref, which could let parent component call child function :saveDisplayedVideo. So the saveDisplayedVideo the the key point.